# How to store multi select values in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, multi-select

I have a form which stores News.

[image]

Here I am using Multiselect and I want to save all the selected option in the table as say  Users,staff,cinemahall as a string.

My controller function to store values is

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{

    $input=$request->all();

    General_news::create($input);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

This function store the all submitted fields but for multiselect it stores only last option i.e cinemahall

[image]

When form is submitted all selected options are displayed but it's not saving in database table properly.

help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the html markup ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Make sure you set the name attribute to an array

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="news[]" id="news">
```

To store it as string separated by commas

```
$news = $request->input('news');
$news = implode(',', $news);
```

You have a string which will look like `Users,staff,cinemahall`. Now, instead to retrieve all input, you may need to retrieve it one by one, since you need to mutate the `news` value. Additionally, you can also use `except()` method to exclude `news` from mass getting all value.

```
$news = $request->input('news');
$news = implode(',', $news);

$input = $request->except('news');
//Assign the "mutated" news value to $input
$input['news'] = $news;

General_news::create($input);
return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, one more query, can you please assist me doing reverse of this, now while editing I want to fetch the string from table and show it as multiselect.

Comment: To convert a string into array, you can use `explode(',', $string);`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Chay22

you could also use Mutators and  Accessor https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

```
public function setFooAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['foo'] = implode(',',$value);
}

public function getFooAttribute($value)
{
    return explode(',',$value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a multiselect, that probably means that you need a many to many relationship and a pivot table. Kind of like how `posts` can belong to many `tags` and `tags` can belong to many `posts`.

In your case this would probably be between `news` and the `news_types` tables.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I want to store this as a string in single table instead of maintaining multiple tables and their relationship.... I know my approach doesn't fit when it comes to Normalization of Database....