# How to get value of multi select in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, adminlte

I am using multi select of [adminlte](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/forms/advanced.html). I wan't to get value of multi select, How can I get it

[image]

Output of **dd($request)**

[image]

**VIEW**

```
<select id="leave_status" name="leave_status[]" title="Leave Status" 
  class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple">       
   <option value="1">Alabama</option>
   <option value="2">Alaska</option>
   <option value="3">California</option>
   <option value="4">Delaware</option>
   <option value="5">Tennessee</option>
   <option value="6">Texas</option>
   <option value="7">Washington</option>
</select>
```

**Controller**

```
function searchLeaveStatus(Request $request){
       $status = $request->input('leave_status');
       $status = implode(',', $status);
       $leave_list = LeaveStatus::whereIn('leave_status', $status)->get();
       dd(leave_list );
   }
```

**Output**

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38289043/8830631

Comment: @UsmanJdn I already find that but its not working, its give me error Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Are you sure you using `$request->input('leave_status')` ? You don't need to put `[]` here.

Comment: @GiedriusKiršys I update my question for better information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you are imploding that array ... `whereIn` is going to try an iterate the `$values` arg (2nd arg) you are passing in.

```
LeaveStatus::whereIn('leave_status', $request->input('leave_status', []))->get();
```

[Laravel Docs - 5.4 - Query Builder - Wheres - whereIn/whereNotIn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses)

[Laravel Docs - 5.4 - Requests - Retrieving Input - Retrieving Input Value](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#retrieving-input)

Answer (score 4):

You must send data to the controller with a function like this:

```
function getData(Request $request){
    $items = $request->get('leave_status');
    $selected_items = '';
    foreach($items as $item){
        \\ do something
        $selected_items .= $item.',';
    }
    dd($selected_items);
}
```

with this, you can get selected items.