# How to save multiple select in database?

Tags: database, laravel

I have a multi-select option and i want to save all record in database, now it's saving only the last one, how can I do that? I need to save multi-select from `tags` with comma (`,`) between.  .
**Here is my controller and what I tried**

```
$news = News::create([
                        'locale' => Session::get('admin_locale'),
                        'title' => $request['title'],
                        'slug' => Slugify::slugify($request['title']),
                        'news_class' => $request['news_class'],
                        'description' => $request['description'],
                        'tag' => $request['tag'],
                        'tags' => $request->input['tags'],
                        'category' => 'news',
                        'category_id' => $request['category_id'],
                        'metatitle' => $request['title'],
                        'metadescription' => substr(strip_tags($request['description']), 0, 160),
                        'image' => $image,
                    ]);
```

**Here is my view:**

```
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mt-100 col-md-12 g-mb-30" >
    <div class="col-md-12"   > 
        <label class="g-mb-10">Tags</label>
        <select id="choices-multiple-remove-button" placeholder="Select" multiple title="Category Talent" name="tags">

                @foreach($news as $tag)
                            <option value="{{ $tag->tag }}">{{ $tag->tag }}</option>
                @endforeach 
        </select> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what type is your `tags` field on the table? and I assume you meant `$request->input('tags')` instead of `$request->input['tags']`?

Comment: It is `varchar(255)`.

Comment: so how do you want to save multiple tags into that field? comma separated list?

Comment: With comma between. ( `tag1,tag2,tag3`).

Comment: please check this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38288899/how-to-store-multi-select-values-in-laravel-5-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass multiple values you probably want to rename your input to be an array:

```
<select ... name="tags[]">
```

Then on the server side you should receive them as an array under the input `tags`:

```
$tags = $request->input('tags', []);
```

You can join the array elements with `implode` to get a string representation:

```
$tags = implode(',', $tags);
```

[PHP Manual - Function Reference - Text Processing - Strings - Functions - `implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$news = News::create([
    ...
    'tags' => implode(',', $request->input('tags', [])),
    ...
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is that the correct way? https://jsfiddle.net/pfsgy2rx/

Comment: Thanks, works great! I have another question : Is there a possibility to have a select option ( with 3 options - Paul, Alex, Type a custom name), and have `name="tags"` on both ? Like, if Paul and Alex is ok, pick them, other type a name in an input with same name.

Comment: with javascript you could have some type of select that could let you pick from predefined options and then be able to enter your own, something like select2 perhaps .... or you could just have both inputs be named `tags[]` so you end up with an array